# Does using html 'confirm' method considered good practice?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to warn a user when he is about to discard changes in a form when switching to another page.

Is `if (!confirm("Are you sure")) return false;...` kind of message considered good practice?
Should I use a modalpanel for that? (More work)

Thanks!

Comment: Well it's a matter of opinion. I don't mind the built-in confirm for that purpose, though I'd make the actual message a bit more meaningful than in your example.

Comment: I would always use confirm for that kind of purpose.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I decided it's a manner of opinion and voted to close my own question :-)

Comment: It *is* a matter of opinion but I would like to venture mine:  the confirm is OK but not great.  If you want a professional, clean site, use jQuery or something to generate a nice HTML popup.  Second, if you can possibly avoid it, don't do confirm dialogs at all.   They're annoying and often disregarded. Undo is much, much better, if it's at all possible.

Comment: @Malvolio Thanks. Undo is possible but would take too much effort to implement. In filling forms I think it is customary to inform the user that he is about to lose the temporary values he has filled in (The other option would be to keep a draft, but as I said, too much work for this version and applies more to document writing and not form filling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces to this question:

1. If using `confirm()` is considered good practice.
2. If this will work to prevent users from leaving the page.

The two principles on which to judge the first part are: (1) never throw away user input and  (2) don't halt a user's flow. `confirm()` dialogs are modal, which means they stop users in their tracks. They are forced to answer the question without moving on. Generally, this is bad. If you can do it in a way that doesn't stop the user's flow, that is better. (For example, storing the input in a cookie or on the server or emailing a link to the user to finish the form later.) If you can't find another way, a modal dialog might be better than losing the data entered.

For the second part it depends on your implementation whether this will work or not. I have a feeling it won't because the user can always type something into the address bar to get away from your page. The surest way to prompt a user before leaving the page no matter the escape vector is to use the `window` object's `onbeforeunload` event and return a string. Implementation details at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

[image: window.onbeforeunload]